# TimeStamp to String Android

Tags: android, string, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

Server gives me time in this format:

```
 Tue Jan 10 03:48:45 GMT+05:30 2017"
```

I want to convert it into:

```
Tue,Jan 2017"
```

I have searched google for a while now, still no luck. How can I do this?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat for that.

Comment: try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("Tue Jan 10 03:48:45 GMT+05:30 2017");
        
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            System.out.println(outputFormat.format(myDate));
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Thanks @DeepakGoyal. It works, sorry for the late reply, was stationed in a remote area, no internet.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to convert one time format to another:

```
public static String formatDateFromOnetoAnother(String date) {
    String resultformat = "EEE,MMM dd";
    String givenformat = "EEE MMM dd zZ yyyy";
    String result = "";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1;
    try {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(givenformat);
        sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(resultformat);
        result = sdf1.format(sdf.parse(date));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } finally {
        sdf = null;
        sdf1 = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```